# Using IConfiguration methods like Bind and GetConnectionString when using Azure Key Vault Configuration Provider for secrets/config

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

So we are in the process of converting our next generation product stack to run in Azure (consists of angular client layer, web api layer, a set of Azure functions for backend processing and Azure sql database as well as several other Azure PAAS services such as Stream Analytics, Event Grid, Azure Tables, Blobs, etc.).

First step was to fully support DI in ASP.NET Core.  Next step was to migrate our configuration model from using appsettings.json to using Azure Key Vault for any settings that included secrets or needed to be consumed by other Azure services that might be sharing middle tier packages and need connection strings, secrets and other shared configuration (i.e. single sourced config).

The strategy was to use Azure Key Vault Configuration Provider with Managed Service Identities.  We thought we would be able to "lift and shift" a majority of our candidate config sections in appsettings.json to be secrets in Azure Key Vault by keying them by config section name in Key Vault where the secret value is the JSON copied and pasted from appsettings.json into the secret value in Key Vault without any additional code changes.

Our hope was that in doing so we would be able to consume the sections coming from key vault exactly the same way that we did when they were stored in appsettings.json.  Our configuration objects are not simple 1:1 key:value pairs but actually strongly typed entities.  With appsettings.json this works cleanly using `IConfiguration.Bind` calls or in the case of connection strings `IConfiguration.GetConnectionString` calls.  Likewise with `services.Configure<T>(Configuration.GetSection("SectionName"))` calls for registering the config sections for IOptions support.

After going through this process we discovered that when trying to consume config sections from Key Vault that contain JSON we can't use the `IConfiguration.Bind` and `IConfiguration.GetConnectionString` methods as is because they don't seem to recognize the value coming back as JSON and therefore don't bind unless we do something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Configuration.GetSection("SectionName").Value)`

This results in our `services.Configure<T>(Configuration.GetSection("SectionName"));` looking more like this...

```
services.Configure<T>(options =>
            {
                var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Configuration.GetSection("ConfigTypeName").Value);
                options.Property = config.Property;
            });
```

This works, but it feels like a code smell...  Now anytime we need to extend a ConfigType we also have to make sure we update the code in Startup.cs to ensure that the `services.Configure<T>` calls copy all properties via the `options =>` override.  This also means our startup code needs to know if a configuration property is coming from key vault or appsettings.json

Question is are we doing this wrong?  Is there another way we should be approaching this?  It seems obvious that the Azure Key Vault Configuration Provider should in theory behave like any other provider such as the file provider for appsettings.json.  Happy to find out we are missing something obvious here and curious to discover why this doesn't work like it "seems like it should".

Comment: The configuration system doesn't assume JSON anywhere so no there's nothing obvious here. You can change your keyvault to store keys in the extended format or extend the provider to parse the JSON within keys and expand it into the expected format.

Comment: Ah yes, fair point, the provider is agnostic...  I just got caught up in appsettings.json being the preferred way to deal with settings in core and made the leap that a keyvault settings provider would have some level of support for json secret values.  I will look into extending the provider, seems like it might be a handy solution to have when just looking to lift and shift from appsettings.json to keyvault.  Thanks!.